# XPath filter by attribute and return distinct values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

From the following I need to return a distinct list of values with the `Category` attribute.

```
<root>
    <classifications>
        <classification name="Category">Category One</classification>
        <classification name="Sub-Category">Sub-Category One</classification>
    </classifications>
    <classifications>
        <classification name="Category">Category Two</classification>
        <classification name="Sub-Category">Sub-Category One</classification>
    </classifications>
    <classifications>
        <classification name="Category">Category One</classification>
        <classification name="Sub-Category">Sub-Category Two</classification>
    </classifications>
    <classifications>
        <classification name="Category">Category Three</classification>
        <classification name="Sub-Category">Sub-Category One</classification>
    </classifications>
    <classifications>
        <classification name="Category">Category One</classification>
        <classification name="Sub-Category">Sub-Category Two</classification>
    </classifications>
    <classifications>
        <classification name="Category">Category Two</classification>
        <classification name="Sub-Category">Sub-Category One</classification>
    </classifications>
</root>
```

Using `classifications/classification[@name="Category"]` I get:

```
Category One
Category Two
Category One
Category Three
Category One
Category Two
```

What I need is:

```
Category One
Category Two
Category Three
```

Comment: I changed the closing elements from `Classification` to `classification` to make the XML well-formed.

Comment: If you're using XSLT (as opposed to just XPath) and want to get distinct values, then use the [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Note also that some XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath will select distinct elements:

```
//classification[@name = "Category" and not(preceding::classification = .)]
```

or more specific:

```
//classification[@name = "Category" 
    and not(preceding::classification[@name = "Category"] = .)
]
```

Comment: This returned:
Category One, Category Two, Category Three
Category One, Category Two, Category Three
Category One, Category Two, Category Three
Category One, Category Two, Category Three
Category One, Category Two, Category Three
Category One, Category Two, Category Three

Comment: thanks that helped a lot. The issue was with my row selection on file import.

Comment: @Mark, no worries. If this works for you, please accept this as an answer.

Comment: Do note that `preceding` axe will traverse the document up in the jerarquia.

Answer (score 0):

For those able to use XPath 2.0 and above:

An alternative approach that may be more flexible, and appears to be more efficient (at least in Saxon 9.8.0) is:

```
distinct-values(//classification[@name = 'Category'])
```

Comment: This is being used in the Drupal views_xml_backend module and returns the following error "xmlXPathCompOpEval: function distinct-values not found", I believe it's XPATH 1.0.

Comment: @Mark, apologies for missing the `xpath-1.0` tag.